# recursive function will not return as expected

Tags: vb.net, function, recursion, console

I am using the following code for finding the exact match.

Using a recursive function.

But it will not return any value even after the execution of return statement:

```
   Public Function findMatch(ByVal startval As Integer, ByVal endVal As Integer) As Integer
        Dim mid As Integer = Ceiling((startval + endVal) / 2)
        Dim value As Integer = 110
        If mid = value Then
            Return mid
        ElseIf mid > value Then
            findMatch(startval, mid)
        ElseIf mid < value Then
            findMatch(mid, endVal)
        End If
    End Function
```

Whythis function is not returning any value? After executing the return the control is goes to the `End Function` and then to `findMatch(startval, mid)` and hence continuous the steps not return any value. I am looking for a reason or a solution not for an alternate method to find the match value.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why this function is not returning any value?

Because you don't *return* the value, use `Return findMatch(startval, mid)`:

```
Public Function findMatch(ByVal startval As Integer, ByVal endVal As Integer) As Integer
    Dim mid As Integer = Ceiling((startval + endVal) / 2)
    Dim value As Integer = 110
    If mid = value Then
        Return mid
    ElseIf mid > value Then
        Return findMatch(startval, mid)
    ElseIf mid < value Then
        Return findMatch(mid, endVal)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Does VB not have a warning that not all paths return a value?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: it's just a compiler warning and not an error. By the way, this warning is still active because there is no `Else` in the `If`, only `ElseIf`.